# Recorrer un archivo txt StreamReader

Tags: c#, text, stream

Estoy tratando de recorrer un archivo de txt con **StreamReader**, el problema que tengo es que nunca puedo pasar de la primer fila de mi archivo de txt y no entiendo por qué.

He tratado con un **for** y con un **while** pero solo me ciclo sobre la primera fila infinitamente.

```
var file = Request.Files[0]; //
string content = new StreamReader(file.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

               using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
                {
                    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        var linea = reader.ReadLine();

                        var a = linea.Substring(0, linea.IndexOf("\n", 0));
                        Extraer(a);


                    }
                }
```

Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal o como mejor mi método?

Comment: Si vas a leer linea a linea no debes usar la función `ReadToEnd()`. Por eso te da error. Elimina la llamada a esa función y debería funcionarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por su tiempo pero terminé haciendo esto y me funciona bastante bien.

```js
string content = new StreamReader(file.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

string[] lines = content.Split(new char[] {
  '\n'
});
int conx = lines.Length;

foreach(string item in lines) {
  string arow = item;
  if (arow != "") {
    Extraer(arow);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias evaluar usar el `ReadLine()`

```
var file = Request.Files[0]; 

using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream)) 
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        var linea = reader.ReadLine();

        var a = linea.Substring(0, linea.IndexOf("\n", 0));
        Extraer(a);
    }
}
```

como veras de esta forma puedes leer linea a linea

Comment: me manda un error de caracteres invalidos en file.InpuSteam le mando esto como new StreamReader
>                   string content = new StreamReader(file.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto:

```
int counter = 0;  
string line;
// Lee la fila y muestra en pantalla linea por linea.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt"); 
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  {
    System.Console.WriteLine (line);  
    counter++;  
}
file.Close(); 
System.Console.WriteLine("There were {0} lines.", counter); 
// Suspende.
System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: explica tu código, ya que las respuestas que no tienen explicación son consideradas de baja calidad